# Fetch values from xml tag to comma seperated text file in unix

Tags: python, shell, unix, sh, aix

We are having xml file which consist of xml tags of different processes running on machines.I want to fetch names of all processes along with it's start,stop command too and save it as comma separated for each process.

> *Example of one of tag in file is below*:-

< PROCESS NAME="Anonymous" TEMP="No" >

< Description>Bla Bla Bla< /Description >

< LogFile>${PROCESS_LOG}< /LogFile >

< User="ABC" >

< Start >

< Command>STARTPROCESS< /Command >

< Parameters>12< /Parameters >

< /Start >

< Stop >

< Command>STOPPROCESS< /Command >

< /Stop >

< SearchCriteria >

< ExeName="SREACH12" >

< Parameters>PROCESS12< /Parameters >

< /ExeName >

< /SearchCriteria >

< /User >

< /PROCESS >

*

> I Want output as below in text file :-

- Anonymous,STARTPROCESS 12,STOPPROCESS,SREACH12 PROCESS12

Please note that there are multiple tags like this in file, so i want all of them same as above.
Something in shell will also work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use re.

```
import re
text ='< PROCESS NAME="Anonymous" TEMP="No" > \
< Description>Bla Bla Bla< /Description > \
< LogFile>${PROCESS_LOG}< /LogFile >\
< User="ABC" >\
< Start >\
< Command>STARTPROCESS< /Command >\
< Parameters>12< /Parameters >\
< /Start >\
< Stop >\
< Command>STOPPROCESS< /Command >\
< /Stop >\
< SearchCriteria >\
< ExeName="SREACH12" >\
< Parameters>PROCESS12< /Parameters >\
< /ExeName >\
< /SearchCriteria >\
< /User >'

# Target: Anonymous,STARTPROCESS 12,STOPPROCESS,SREACH12 PROCESS12

pName =  re.findall(r'PROCESS NAME="(.+?)" TEMP', text)
commands =  re.findall(r'< Command>(.+?)< /Command >', text)
params =  re.findall(r'< Parameters>(.+?)< /Parameters >', text)
exeName =  re.findall(r'< ExeName="(.+?)" >', text)

myOutput = pName[0]+","+commands[0]+" "+params[0]+","+commands[1]+","+exeName[0]+" "+params[1]
print(myOutput)
```

Prints:

```
Anonymous,STARTPROCESS 12,STOPPROCESS,SREACH12 PROCESS12
```

Comment: thanks for the help. But in above example i have given only one tag and i'm having multiple tags like above in xml file. So , i need to fetch those details from xml file for all.

Comment: You can get data from other tags similar way. Just change leading and tailing match parameters accordingly for each re.match(). You may have to make recursive check for command and params of each pName.